# Rendering Grails content in Twitter Bootstrap modal

Tags: grails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am trying to render the outcome of an action into a modal (twitter bootstrap). Unfortunately I do not get this to work.

Before I was generating a link within an each iterator:

```
<g:link action="perform" id="${exerciseInstance.id}">
   <h2>${fieldValue(bean: exerciseInstance, field: "title")}: (${exerciseInstance.questions.size()} Questions)</h2>
 </g:link>
```

Instead of rendering a complete new site I rather want the quiz to be presented in a modal. Therefore I tried a simple twitter bootstrap modal example:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">${fieldValue(bean: exerciseInstance, field: "title")}</a>
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" style="display: none; ">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3>Test</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    --> This is where the content should go <--
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What issue are you facing ? There's nothing specific to grails - If you are able to display static text into your bootstrap modal you should be able to display dynamic text just by replacing your static text with groovy expression ${}

provide details on what exact issue are you facing ?

Comment: I am trying to have a web flow (http://www.springsource.org/spring-web-flow) inside the modal. Like be a quiz containing n questions and displaying the result at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asking for the "best way" on SO is a dangerous game.  There probably isn't a best.  Just different approaches.  I'll give you one that I use utilizing jQuery's [$.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.

```
$("#myModal .modal-body").load(url);
```

It really is that simple.  Obviously, adjust your load() function if you need to pass in parameters, provide a callback function, etc.  Your controller's action would just render a template containing the HTML you want in your modal-body.  This isn't really even Grails specific. This approach would work with any server side tech.